# Injury that leaves you hospitalized a week

Tags: diseases

My protagonist has a work that requires a lot of walking. Now he needs an excuse to be away from work for 5-7 days but after that be able to work normal again without raising any suspicion.

I was thinking something along slipping and injuring a foot. The problem is that I need something that is more "black and white", first you are injured and can't walk at all and suddenly the next day you are back to at least 80-90 % of your walking capacity. If you injure a foot, after a while, you are expected to walk short distances and slowly increasing the load to restore strength and mobility.

It would be good if whatever we are talking about requires 2-3 days at a hospital, then another 3-4 rest at home and finally you are back at almost full walking capacity.

Context: current western society with access to modern healthcare and hospitals.

Comment: What's wrong with a twisted ankle? One week recovery time is is perfectly possible for an uncomplicated ankle sprain.

Comment: No injury has a fixed amount of time to heal. Some people heal faster than others.

Answer (score 3):

[Kidney stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_stone_disease). You’re incapable of doing anything while suffering from the stone, but back to normal pretty much immediately as soon as it’s removed. Five to seven days is a plausible timescale from onset to recovery.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want him away from work then [Norovirus](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/norovirus/) will do the trick.

Three days on the john with your head in a bucket, then 3 days contagious when nobody wants you anywhere near them.

When you call in sick with that it's a week off no questions asked, but by the time you're back at work, you're back at full strength.

Answer (score 1):

Suspicion for corona-virus flu, that turned to be simple cold.
When your character returned from China, he/she had coughs and fever. He/she was isolated in hospital for few days, and his/her disease  turned to be simple flu, that usually heals by itself in few days with symptomatic therapy (painkillers, antipyretic medicine, vitamins, immune system stimulators).